# Python: how to get a parent instance from a child instance

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

If I have two child classes both inherit from the same parent class

```
    class Parent(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.name = 'parent'
            self.position = 0

    class FirstChild(Parent):
        def __init__(self):
            self.speed = 1

    class SecondChild(Parent):
        def __init__(self):
            self.final = 100

        def remaining_distance(self):
            print('Remaining distance is %i.' %(self.final - self.position)
```

Now I define an instance from FirstChild.

```
    Child1 = FirstChild()
```

I want to use a method from SecondChild on Child1. How should I do that?
I know

```
    SecondChild.remaining_distance(Child1)
```

will get me an error message. Is there any code that errorlessly achieves the effect intended?

Thank you :)

Comment: This can't be done, FirstChild and SecondChild don't share anything. Could you put the remaining_distance function into Parent?

Comment: You just cannot, the `Child1` is not an instance of `SecondChild`.

Comment: `remaining_distance` should obviously be a method of `Parent` or `FirstChild`.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a child class instance is also an instance of parent class 
for example in  the document:

```
    class Foo(object):
        def __init__(self):
            print "foo init"

    class Bar(object):
        def __init__(self):
            print "bar init"

    class FooBar(Foo, Bar):
        def __init__(self):
            print "foobar init"
            super(FooBar, self).__init__()

    a = FooBar()
```

**Output:**

```
    foobar init
    foo init
```

But it doesn't mean that Bar class is not inherited. An instance of final FooBar class is also an instance of Bar class and Foo class.

```
print isinstance(a,FooBar)
print isinstance(a,Foo)  
print isinstance(a,Bar)
```

**OutPut**

```
True
True
True
```

In your example, First and Second child are both has same parent class but so they can share only parent class variable or method because they both share parent class scope, both child can't share their own method or variable because they are not sharing their scope